# 2 Column Text plain text or markdown editor?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor of some kind where it's split down the middle when editing 2 separate files.

I'm trying to translate some text and it would be helpful if I could have English and its meaning on 1 side and Spanish on the other.

Is there anything like this for OS X?

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) where you can split a window horizontally:

[image: horizontally]

vertically:

[image: vertically]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-emacs5/image03.jpg))</sub>

or in a more complicated fashion:

[image: complicated]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Sublime Text 3 beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). You can switch to 2 column mode from View -> Layout -> Columns: 2, or Cmd+Option+2. The app supports multiple syntax highlighting options (including markdown), but doesn't display formatted markdown.

Comment: hmm.. i have sublime text and I guess I could use that but is there anything that will work with formatted markdown? just looking for something extremely simple

Comment: I guess you could use [Mou](http://mouapp.com/) with two windows side by side...

Answer (score 0):

VIM will accomplish this. The mac version is [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

You can accomplish what you want by opening one file, then from the menu:

`File > Split Diff with...`

The output will look like this:
[image]
with differences highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this perfectly with Visual Studio Code. There's even a Markdown preview there.

[image: Markdown preview in Visual Studio Code]